# The Javascript v8 engine and Web APIs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8

I have been reading into the internals of Javascript (in the context of the chrome browser) and I have a few questions that I can't seem to find proper answers to.

As per my understanding:

- Core Javascript (as per ECMA specification) is included in the V8
  engine.
- Functions like `settimeout` are provided by the browser's Web APIs.
- The V8 engine includes a call stack and any Javascript that is to be
  executed gets pushed on to this stack.
- Non-standard functions are then called via Web APIs.
- These on completion gets pushed to a callback queue.
- Once the stack is empty, anything on the callback queue gets pushed
  onto the stack by the event loop.

My question is When the V8 engine interprets Javascript code, how does it know that a particular function is from the Web APIs? And how are Web APIs actually linked with the engine?

Comment: [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223)

Comment: This is a huge question. Consider splitting it up into small questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

APIs like `setTimeout()` are added to the `global` object in Javascript.   When the JS engine is looking to resolve a symbol, it starts in the local scope and goes up a chain of scopes.  At the very end of the chain is the `global` scope.

The host environment can, as part of initializing the V8 engine, add it's own APIs to the global scope in the V8 engine and that's exactly what a browser does for things it needs that aren't already built into V8.

The notion of the global object in a browser is a bit messier than it probably should be.  For many years, the global object was the `window` object.  All globally accessible host environment functions like `setTimeout()` are properties of the `window` object.

Similarly, declaring any variables at the top level scope in a browser would automatically make those variables be properties of the `window` object.

This got messy fast.  When the new `class` keyword came along, they decided to not continue to make this mess worse so classes declared at the top level scope in a browser are available globally, but are not added as properties of the `window` object.

When the node.js environment came along, they organized user code into modules and the goal was to have as few global variables as possible.  In that environment global variables are properties of an object named `global`.  Variables you declare at the top level in node.js modules are scoped only to within the module.  Nothing automatically becomes a global variable, but you can explicitly assign a new property to the `global` object if you want to such as:

```
global.myProperty = 3;
```

though that is strongly discourage in the node.js modular design.

So, any API outside of the ECMAScript specification that is added at the top level in Javascript in the browser like `setTimeout()` is added to the `global` object by the browser environment when it is initializing the V8 engine.

Comment: So is the global object defined within V8 and once the browser loads, these Web API functions are added to the global object by the browser?

Comment: @fsociety - As part of initializing a Javascript environment, the host environment can create objects (beyond what is part of ECMAScript itself) in that Javascript environment to make them available to any scripts run in that environment.

Comment: @fsociety - I added a bunch more to my answer.

Comment: I see. So once the function is in the global object, and is ready for execution, the V8 engine will treat it as any other function and push it onto the call-stack? And I assume once this function is processed on the stack, whatever definition will be executed; Which in the case of `setTimeout` would be linked to further function calls to some low-level implementation outside of the global scope (?).

Comment: @fsociety - It is just any other function as far as the JS engine is concerned.  When you call it, it will get pushed onto the call stack and its code will execute.  The code behind that function may be either all Javascript or it may have bindings to native code (V8 has a developer API for binding native code to a JS function).  `setTimeout()` does indeed bind to some native code to manage and fire timers.